Windows laptop sometimes sleeps instead of shutting down
So I have an HP laptop that runs Windows 11. Ever since I've gotten it, whenever I click "Shut Down" from the Start Menu and try and shut it down, about 25% of the time the laptop just sleeps instead, and the LED on the power button remains switched on. The battery fully drains overnight if left like this. It properly shuts down the remaining 75% of the time.
Does anyone know whether this issue is related to the UEFI/BIOS? Or does this have to be a hardware issue?
I close all my programs every time I shut down the laptop, so I'm pretty sure it's not some random program causing this issue.
There are a lot of past questions on this forum about the laptop shutting down instead of sleeping, but not vice versa, hence why I'm asking the question here.
Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It could be Windows or some application is working in the background, refusing to be shutdown. An email client might be in the middle of downloading messages; an update might be running; etc.
You can force shutdown a bit with a desktop shortcut with the following text: shutdown.exe /s /t 00.
Click that shortcut to shut down immediately, or add a keyboard shortcut to make it easier yet (but don't make it one you'd be likely to hit accidentally ;-).
More forceful is shutdown.exe /f /s /t 00, which would abruptly terminate any ongoing process. That will shut the PC, but might cause loss of data.
